# How should I Display Native Ads in a SingleChildScrollView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob

I am integrating native AdMob ads into my Flutter project within a scrollable content area. I want to display multiple ads as the user scrolls through the content. After approximately every three paragraphs, I want to insert an ad. The total number of ads I intend to display is between two and three. My question is whether this method of loading and displaying ads violates AdMob policies, based on the code I've provided. If not, is it possible to add more ad references to the widget tree and display them?

```
    //How I Load the Ads
    NativeAd loadAdmobNativeAd(){
    NativeAd nativeAd = NativeAd(
        adUnitId: _nativeadUnitId,
        listener: NativeAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      print('$NativeAd loaded.');
      setState(() {
        _nativeAdIsLoaded = true;
      });
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
    // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
    print('$NativeAd failedToLoad: $error');
    ad.dispose();
    },
    onAdClicked: (ad) {},
    onAdImpression: (ad) {},
    onAdClosed: (ad) {},
    onAdOpened: (ad) {},
    onAdWillDismissScreen: (ad) {},
    onPaidEvent: (ad, valueMicros, precision, currencyCode) {},
    ),
    request: const AdRequest(),
    nativeTemplateStyle: NativeTemplateStyle(
    templateType: TemplateType.medium,
    mainBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
    cornerRadius: 10.0,
    callToActionTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
    textColor: Colors.cyan,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
      style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.monospace,
      size: 16.0,
    ),
      primaryTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
        textColor: Colors.red,
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
        style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.italic,
        size: 16.0,
      ),
      secondaryTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
        textColor: Colors.green,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.bold,
        size: 16.0,
      ),
      tertiaryTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
        textColor: Colors.brown,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.normal,
        size: 16.0,
      ),
    ),
    );
    nativeAd.load();
    return nativeAd;
  }
```

```
//How I reference the Ads before adding to the widget tree.
void referenceNativeAds(){
    _nativeAd1 = loadAdmobNativeAd();
    _nativeAd2 = loadAdmobNativeAd();
  }
```

```
//How I display the ads
body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                        //Ads Container
                        if (_nativeAd2 != null) Container(
                            child: ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                minWidth: 320, // minimum recommended width
                                minHeight: 320, // minimum recommended height
                                maxWidth: 400,
                                maxHeight: 400,
                              ),
                              child: AdWidget(ad: _nativeAd2!),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            personalTraits,
                            //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: GoogleFonts.gabriela(
                              textStyle:
                              TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //Ad Conatainer
                          if (_nativeAd1 != null) Container(
                            child: ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                minWidth: 320, // minimum recommended width
                                minHeight: 320, // minimum recommended height
                                maxWidth: 400,
                                maxHeight: 400,
                              ),
                              child: AdWidget(ad: _nativeAd1!),
                            ),
                          ),
```